# different between gazebo and rviz

Tags: ros, gazebo, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone , i am a beginner for ros and i want to simulator a robot with sensor and can send odom msgs ,i already built a simple robot model , using arbotix and rviz and i can teleop it ; to add more , may i learn gazebo? where can i find a good tutorials? and what is gazebo , a visual tools like rviz ? or a simulator tools ? will i use gazebo to simulator and visual in rviz?
thx for help~ and merry christmas~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200044/different-between-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is the actual real world physics simulator that you will set up a world and simulate your robot moving around. Rviz is the visualization software, that will allow you to view that gazebo data (if you are simulating) or real world data (if you are not using gazebo, but a real robot).

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-26**:
thank you very much